# Currency Converter function in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, vuejs3

I'm trying to implement a convert() function in a Vue3 project.

I have a functions.js file to store some "global" basic functions

```
import axios from 'axios'

let functions = {}

functions.convert = async (amount, currencySetting) => {
  const result = await getRate(currencySetting)
  const rateData = result.data
  const rate = rateData[`EUR_${currencySetting}`]
  const converted = rate * amount
  return Math.round(converted)
}

function getRate(currency) {
  const apiKey = process.env.VUE_APP_CURRENCY_API_KEY
  return axios.get(
    `https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=EUR_${currency}&compact=ultra&apiKey=${apiKey}`
  )
}

export default functions
```

I'm calling the function inside a component like this

```
<script>
import functions from '@/functions.js'

export default {
  name: 'SltResult',
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formattedIrp() {
      if (this.data.irp != 'n/a') {
        const currencySetting = this.$store.state.currency.currency
        if (currencySetting != 'EUR') {
            const convertedIrp = functions.convert(this.data.irp, currencySetting)
            return convertedIrp + currencySetting
        } else {
            return this.data.irp + '€'
        }
      }
      return this.data.irp
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work properly, I only get a pending Promise result... Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm learning Vue and JS....

Comment: My first guess is that the computed function is not async and it's calling an async function, you will probably want to use an observer which calls a function that performs the request and then updates `formattedIrp` which is instead inside of `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two problems with your code.

1. Logical issue. It doesn't make sense to have ajax call inside a computed property, just use a normal method.
2. Syntax issue. Your `convert` function is async, which means you need to wait for it to get the value.

This is a working version of your code:

```
<script>
import functions from '@/functions.js'

export default {
  name: 'SltResult',
  data: () => ({
    formattedIrp: null,
  }),
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      if (this.data.irp != 'n/a') {
        const currencySetting = this.$store.state.currency.currency
        if (currencySetting != 'EUR') {
          functions.convert(this.data.irp, currencySetting).then(result => {
            this.formattedIrp = result + currencySetting;
          })
        } else {
            this.formattedIrp = this.data.irp + '€'
        }
      }
      this.formattedIrp = this.data.irp
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Haitham, I've only changed created() to updated() and it is now working!

Comment: Yes, `created` was a mistake. It should be `mounted` if it the value of `irp` won't change, or `updated` if the value might change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const getRate = async (currency) => {
  const apiKey = process.env.VUE_APP_CURRENCY_API_KEY
  return (await axios.get(
    `https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=EUR_${currency}&compact=ultra&apiKey=${apiKey}`
  ))
}
```